# How to render a NextJs component as string?

Tags: next.js, components, render, codeblocks

I am trying to create a NextJs application component library, but I have a problem, I can't render my components in string.

Let me explain: I have created an avatar component for example. On my frontend, I have a tab with the final rendering on one side, and the code to copy on the other side. But I can't import my component as a string.

Here are my 3 main files.

**1/ My component**

```
import Image from "next/image";
import cn from "clsx";

export type AvatarContent = {
  notif?: boolean;
  group?: boolean;
  title?: string;
  subtitle?: string;
  form?: "circle" | "rounded" | "square";
};

export const Avatar = ({
  form = "circle",
  notif = false,
  group = false,
  title,
  subtitle,
}: AvatarContent) => {
  const members = [
    {
      id: 1,
      image:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669178082499-341906b2ab28?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDN8dG93SlpGc2twR2d8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      image:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521119989659-a83eee488004?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8cG9ydHJhaXR8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      image:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544005313-94ddf0286df2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OHx8cG9ydHJhaXR8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      image:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580489944761-15a19d654956?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fHBvcnRyYWl0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      image:
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581403341630-a6e0b9d2d257?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NTh8fHBvcnRyYWl0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div className={cn(`relative flex items-center ${group && "-space-x-4"}`)}>
      <div
        className={cn(`right-2 h-4 w-4 rounded-full bg-green-400 ring-1 ring-white 
      ${form === "circle" && "bottom-0"}
      ${form === "square" && "-bottom-2"} 
      ${form === "rounded" && "-bottom-2"}
      ${notif === true ? "absolute" : "hidden"}`)}
      />
      {group === false ? (
        <div
          className={cn(
            `h-20 w-20 overflow-hidden 
        ${form === "circle" && "rounded-full"} 
        ${form === "square" && "rounded-none"} 
        ${form === "rounded" && "rounded-lg"}`
          )}
        >
          <Image
            src={
              "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669178082499-341906b2ab28?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHx0b3BpYy1mZWVkfDN8dG93SlpGc2twR2d8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60"
            }
            alt="image"
            width={80}
            height={80}
          />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <>
          {members.map((item) => (
            <div
              key={item.id}
              className={
                "inline-block h-20 w-20 overflow-hidden rounded-full ring-2 ring-white"
              }
            >
              <Image src={item.image} width={80} height={80} alt="image" />
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
      {title && (
        <div className="ml-4 flex flex-col">
          <span className="font-bold">{title}</span>
          <span className="text-sm text-secondary">{subtitle}</span>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**2/ My json file tsx format:**
*(I've left various tests that don't work as comments in my json, on the "code" line.)*

```
import { Avatar } from "@components/elements/Avatar/avatar";

const elements = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Avatar",
    description:
      "Dignissimos earum expedita sunt, reprehenderit eveniet ut asperiores ratione repellat ipsam nobis sint minima nostrum ?  Quos eos, veniam odio excepturi porro ex.",

    tabs: true,
    codes: [
      {
        id: 1,
        preview: <Avatar />,
        title: "Avatars with notification",
        // code : <Avatar />,
        // code: String(<Avatar />),
        // code: JSON.stringify(<Avatar />, null, 2),
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        preview: <Avatar notif={true} />,
        title: "Avatars with notification",
        code: ``,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        preview: <Avatar group={true} />,
        title: "Avatars Group",
        code: ``,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        preview: (
          <Avatar title={"Durant Jean"} subtitle={"Développeur Front"} />
        ),
        title: "Avatar with text",
        code: ``,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default elements;
```

**3/ My library page**

```
import Prism from "prismjs";

export interface TabProps {
  item: Record<string, any>;
}
export const TabsSection = ({ item }: TabProps) => {

useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      Prism.highlightAll();
    }
  }, []);

return (
    <div className="relative max-h-[50vh] w-full !max-w-full overflow-y-scroll rounded-lg bg-gray-800 p-8 text-sm text-gray-200">
        <pre className="whitespace-pre-wrap">
            <code className={`language-tsx`}>{item?.code}</code>
        </pre>
    </div>
)
```

Do you have any suggestion for this problem?